# Git não faz o push para a branch master

Tags: php, linux, git, composer

Estava usando o .git normalmente em meu projeto, ontem digitei alguma coisa errada e o git começou a me devolver um alerta do arquivo index corrompido.

Ok, dei um git reset, voltei um commit e tudo voltou ao normal.

Bom, trabalhei hoje de manhã, a na hora que fui dar um push para o meu servidor, simplesmente não funciona, essa é a mensagem de erro (o terminal de baixo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom, não estou descobrindo o erro, todas as pastas estão com permissão 777, e pertencem ao mesmo grupo e usuário tanto na máquina local como no servidor.

Local: Ubuntu 16.4 LTS
Servidor: Debian 7

Ambas estão na mesma rede.

Comment: Já tentou rodar o comando com `sudo`?

Comment: Esse erro ja foi rodado com sudo aberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUÇÃO:

1 - Criar um nova branch no pc local e setar.

> git checkout -b 'project'

2 - Solicitar o push

> git push --set-upstream origin project

A partir daqui, apenas usar o comando:

> git push

Answer (score 2):

O erro do `git` refere-se a perca ou a não referência entre a sua *branch* local *master* e a *master* remota. Perdendo a referencia do HEAD.

Ao iniciar o projeto você aplicou o comando `git init`?

Isso significa que qualquer pessoa que aplicar o push "forçadamente" para este ramo irá substituir o status existente da cópia de trabalho verificada, ou seja, a referência a HEAD. Isso não é uma coisa boa.

Para resolver isso, você usa um repositório descoberto como um repo "comunitário" (faça isso com `git init --bare`) ou trabalhe com *brands* a partir da master, conforme fez:

```
git checkout -b nome_branch
```

Faça as alterações nesse ramo e aplique `commit`. Em seguida, aplique o *push* seu ramo com `git push origin nome_branch`. Depois disso, seu ramo remoto pode ser "mergeado" no mestre.

Aconselho sempre evitar "commitar" na *master*. Você pode bloquear isso através do site *github*. Crie o hábito de criar *branchs* a partir da master e "mergear" as alterações nela. Só não esqueça de sempre atualizar seu *master* local `git pull` toda vez que for criar uma nova *branch* para sempre ter a cópia atualiza do remoto.

Comment: Eu não estou utilizando o github nesse projeto, meu repositório é interno por se tratar de um sistema intranet, teria como bloquear a branch master para todos os usuários da rede exceto o admin do servidor?

Comment: Até onde eu sei e pelo o que pude pesquisar rapidinho. Esse conceito quem aplica é o github, não o git. Por isso no seu caso já não daria certo. Eu não sei qual o motivo de você ter criado um repositório interno, mas se for apenas para tê-lo como private, há duas soluções no mercado free que podem te ajudar a aplicar o que eu expliquei na resposta. [gogs](https://gogs.io/) e [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/)